# Running my own server with a "developers background"?

Tags: hosting, amazon-ec2, vps

I have a couple of different projects running for the moment - some PHP apps and a few WordPress instances, which all currently are kept at a web hosting company. The contract period time is about to end and I would lie if I wouldn't say that I really had considered making the switch onto a VPS server in the cloud with the prices getting really great.
I am totally in love with the fact of being able to turn the performance up or down when demand increases, or goes away and thereby cut the costs.

With my background as a PHP developer, with only a little hint of Linux (ubuntu) knowledge, I am thoroughly concerned about the security if I should run my own VPS.

Sure, I am able to install and get things running with my current knowledge (and some help by Google), but **is it realistic nowadays to expect that my server (LAMP, really) will stay secure by running out-of the box stuff and keeping it up-to date?**

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com)?

Comment: Hi Joe - I haven't since we're located in Europe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintaining your server is just one more thing to worry about, and if you're a developer, your focus should probably be on development. That said, it needs to make financial sense to go the managed route. If you're just working on toy projects (I've got a $20/month VPS that I use for my personal projects and homepage, and it's pretty hands-off) or if you're just getting off the ground, VPSes have the great advantage of being *cheap* and giving you *lots* of control of your environment. You can even mitigate some of the risk by keeping aggressive backups, since it's easy to redeploy a server quickly.

But, if you get to the point where it won't affect your profitability to do so, you probably should seriously consider getting someone else to take care of infrastructure for you either by buying managed hosting services or hiring someone to do it for you. It all depends on **what you can afford to lose** if you get rooted and how much time you can afford to invest in server management and recovery as opposed to coding.

Comment: I agree. Also I would like to add that you should consider cloud services instead of managed services on dedicated environment, do some trade offs between this different services. At the end thats really depends on you context, how seriously is your service. For toy or business with low requirements.. VPS is one way. I had $17/month VPS monthly: a true nightmare. I really do prefer having $129/month instead on private dedicated server;

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't. We did the same thing because the non-managed VPS are sooo cheap, but unless you really need to install applications or libraries that are not part of standard shared host setups, in my experience, being a pure developer as well, the time spent is never worth it.

Unless, of course, it is your own tiny blog or you just want to play around.

But imagine you (or whichever automation you use) update php, and for some reasons it fails (or worse, you render your current installation unusable) - are you good enough to handle this? And if so, how long will it take you? Do you have a friend at hand who can help?

We, as a small company, are getting rid of our VPSs step-by-step and moving back to our reseller package, hosted at a good hosting provider.

Good question, though.

Answer (score 2):

As for security, I have successfully used Amazon EC2 for a number of things. It's not the cheapest around, but quite comprehensible in shared data stores between instances, connection to S3, running hosts at different hosting centers etc, grouping hosts in different clusters, etc etc.

They have a firewall built in, where you can turn all things off except say, TCP traffic on port 22 for SSH and 80 for web. That combined with something like Ubuntu, where you can easily run updates without worrying much about breakage, is probably all you need from a security point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You need consider cloud computing as a statement of avaibility, not cost.  You can be seriously surprised about the cost at the end.
I already have optioned to use VPS hosting. Good VPS hosting is costly, these days you may find cheap dedicated host compared to VPS. Have look at hivelocity.com – I like their services.

About security, most VPS host company takes care of security for you at the infra-structure level, and some may use antivirus software on files. On dedicated host, you need to take care by yourself or contract managed support services:  a tradoff.
LAMP server is cheap everywhere. You can hire a private VPS and have some security, you may count on services like DNS hosting too – this is trouble to configure. VPS can be your first step as you're doubtful and has no experience on hosting.  Thereafter when you find out the advantages of having your own server, you'll migrate straight to dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

What is acceptable from a security standpoint will differ depending on the people involved, what you want to secure and requirements of the product/service.

For a development server I usually don't care so much, so I usually do some basic securing of the server and then don't pay attention to it again.  My main concern is more of someone getting a session and using my cycles to run something.  I don't normally care about IP so that's not a concern for me.

If I'm setting up a box that has to meet Sarbanes-Oxley, Safe Harbor, or other PII/PCI standards I must meet I would probably go managed just because I don't want the additional security work load.

Somewhere in between is a judgment based on if I want to commit the required time to secure the server to the level I want it secured at.  If I don't want to do it myself I pay someone to do it.

I would be careful about assuming your getting a certain level of security just because your paying someone to manage your server.  I've come across plenty of shops where security is really an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you are considering a move from a web host to a VPS, and wonder if you have the skills to ensure the OS remains secure now that it's under your control?

I guess it's an open-ended question. You are moving from a managed environment to an unmanaged environment, and whether you maintain your environmental security is up to you. If you're running your own server then you need to make sure that default passwords aren't in use (for the database, OS and any services on top), patches are quickly identified and applied, host firewalls are configured properly and suspicious activity alerts are immediately sent to you. Hang on, does your current web host do any of this for you? Without details about your current web host and the planned VPS, you are pretty much comparing apples to oranges.

BTW, I would be somewhat concerned about my LAMP server security, but frankly I would be much more concerned about development errors (SQL injection, XSS) and the packages running on top of my server (default passwords + dev errors).

Answer (score 1):

For a lamp stack, I would probably not do it. It would be a different case if you were using a Platform-as-a-service provider like Windows Azure - by my own experience there is minimal operational overhead and you just upload the app and it runs in a vm (and yes it supports php).

But for Linux there are no such providers that I know of, which means you will have to manage the Operating system, the app frameworks, the web server and anything else that you install on the instance. I wouldn't do it myself. I would consider the options as hiring a person with the relevant experience to do this for me vs the cost of managed services from the vps provider and go with one of those two.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than give you advice about what you should do, or tell you what *I* would do, I'm just going to address your question "is it realistic nowadays to expect that my server (LAMP, really) will stay secure by running out-of the box stuff and keeping it up-to date?"  The answer to this question, in my opinion, is basically yes.

dietbuddha is right, of course:  what constitutes an acceptable level of security depends on the context, but for all but the most security-sensitive purposes, if you're using a current (i.e. supported) distro, with sane defaults, and keeping up with the security updates, then you ought to be fine.

I have two VPSs, each of them currently runs Ubuntu 10.04 server.  On one of them, I spend some time installing and configuring tiger, tripwire, and taking various other security measures.  On the other, I simply installed fail2ban and set security updates to automatic, and left it at that.  They've been running for a few years, now, and I've had no problem with either.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it for fun and for learning purposes. Other than that, don't; you're wasting your own time and a lot of other people's time.

I say this because I've wasted serious time setting up an EC2 instance to host my SVN server and a few other things. I mean, I loved setting everything up and messing w/ the server; I learned a lot especially because I'd never done anything a LINUX server before. However, looking back, I wasted a ton of time and had to keep buggin @Jordan S. Jones for help.